How to change the Money format?
The following code will output something like MYR 1,476.00. How can I have it to output RM 1,476.00?
Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('total_sales')
    ->summarize(Sum::make()->money("myr"))


Either just use standard 3 letter as it is in ISO
or write cast for 2 letter curency such as
return "RM " . number_format($this->aggregate($this->query), 2, ',', '.');

or another approach just use create helper to format as you see fit
function formatToRm($amount)
{
  return "RM " . number_format($amount, 2, ',', '.');
} 

